# How do I connect to a PostgreSQL server using LibreOffice Base?

Tags: postgresql, libreoffice-base

I'm running into errors when I try to connect to a PostgreSQL server on the local machine using LibreOffice Base 3.5 (this applies to LibreOffice 4 as well):

[image: LibreOffice Base data source selection]

The following syntax (`localhost:5432=<database name>`; database name `worktime`) doesn't work:

[image]

When I try to test the connection on the next page, I get the following error:

> Error in database URL 'sdbc:postgresql:localhost:5432=localhost': 
>   invalid connection option "localhost:5432"

What is the correct syntax for the datasource URL?

Comment: I may not ask an SU question especially for that, so I ask you personnally: what do you do when you plug Libre Office into Postgresql ? what kind of help, usefulness does this association offer ? Is it only for editing the content of the database ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland: LibreOffice provides a graphical interface for input and editing of data in the tables as well as a query builder, among other features that make interfacing with the database easier.

Comment: on windows there is also the option to use an ODBC driver, (its a bit too much of a hoop jump to detail in a comment)

Comment: @StephaneRolland You can use postgresql as a source for data in columns in a calc sheet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Ever Forward will answer your question:](http://dcparris.net/2011/07/31/connecting-libreoffice-to-postgresql/)

> This is not an Internet URL, but it functions similarly.  You now need to tell LibreOffice to connect to a specific database on a specific computer:
>
> `dbname=mydb host=localhost`
>
> Use the name of your database in the dbname part.  I used localhost for the host part, since PostgreSQL is on the same computer, but I would need to change that in the event that I want to connect from a remote computer.

Answer (score 16):

I know this Q is answered.. but here is more data information for someone who may stumble across this topic.

Another form of datasource URL is in the format of:

```
dbname=postgres hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5433 user=db_user password=libreoffice
```

I needed the above, because the default port used by LibreBase is 5432, but I needed 5433.

This URL format is discussed at http://ask.libreoffice.org/question/459/generic-form-of-url-for-postgresql/

Answer (score 0):

As I read here: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/windows-libreoffice-6-2-3-postgresql-sdbc-driver-error/41693/8

Like me, this workaround can help you 
Go to 
Edit->Database->Properties... and 
Edit->Database->Connection Type...

Set something like this (according to your values):

**postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb**

Explanation 
host = localhost 
port = 5432 
database to connect = mydb